# Convert shp spatial data to WKT using PHP

Tags: php, shapefile, qgis, dbf, wkt

I am trying to export some shape files to a a MySQL database.

I can read the shp features dbf file using PHP but I want to be able to get the WKT spatial data for each row that I am looping through. I have thought to add a calculated field (geomToWKT) to the shp file fields in qgis, but unfortunately the length of the string field attributes in the dbf file is limited to 254 characters. How can I can get the corresponding wkt for each row?

```
function process_dbf($dbf_path) {
  $db = dbase_open($dbf_path, 0);
  if($db) {
    $record_numbers = dbase_numrecords($db);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $record_numbers; $i++) {
      $row = dbase_get_record_with_names($db, $i);

      $name= $row['name'];
      $name=$row['area'];
      $x=$row['x'];
      $y=$row['y'];
      $notes=$row['notes'];
      $owner=$row['owner'];
      $id=$row['ID'];
      $tel=$row['tel_'];
      $wkt=geomToWKT(geometry); //what I am trying to achieve in PHP
  }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. Finally managed to get it to work.

You will need this [class](https://github.com/fillerwriter/PHP5-Shape-File-Parser). Also, if you are using Windows you will need [this dbase extension](http://hrazdil.info/blog/414-php-dbase-extension-for-php-5-4-windows-nts-ts-vc9) on PHP 5.4

```
include 'PHP5-Shape-File-Parser-master/shpParser.php';
function process_shp($shp_location,$dbf_location) {
$parser=new shpParser();
$parser->load($shp_location);
$db = dbase_open($dbf_location, 0);
$data=$parser->getShapeData();
$i=1;
foreach($data as $shprow) {
    $datarow=dbase_get_record_with_names($db, $i);
    $i++;
    //print_r($shprow); for shp geo spatial data (shp)
    //print_r($datarow); for shp feature data (dbf)
}
}
process_shp('Jerusalem/BeitHanina/entrances/New_Shapefile-new.shp';
'Jerusalem/BeitHanina/entrances/New_Shapefile-new.dbf'); //for example
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this late answer just as a service for the community, since this is one of the questions that pop up when looking for *"converting ESRI Shapefiles to WKT"*.

My [PHP Shapefile](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) library can read and write any ESRI Shapefile and convert it natively from/to **WKT** and **GeoJSON**.

It does not require any third party dependency nor the dBase extension (not available in most modern PHP environments) and it is actively maintained.